# send files from android to PC over wifi

Tags: windows, android, desktop-computer, wifi-transfer

currently i use installed ftp server on android, then connect to WiFi, my PC has same network on it, then i open ftp address on my PC and copy files.

is there a way to send files between android and PC without FTP? if you are suggesting to use USB cable, its not possible because there are lot android to manage with single PC. also it need an identity on each cable.

i wanted to make a program with VB that able to copy files from android, so with just 1 click, i can perform all copy files alternately. but sometimes, it broke the files without notify. so i want to try other way if it is possible

Comment: You **can** transfer files via USB.  I do it all the time.  Connect the lead and use the PC within `file explorer`

Comment: @Chris I think OP is talking about a specific scenario: they want to quickly transfer files from multiple android devices to a single PC. In this case USB might not be optimal. The wording is a bit sloppy though so maybe I misunderstood. Also MTP might not give access to all the files or be slower/buggy, in that case `adb` is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this.  Off the top of my head -

- SMB / SAMBA / Windows file sharing clients and filemanagers abound.
- SSH daemons and scp/sftp clients abound as well.
- A private dropbox type configuration (eg using Owncloud or Nextcloud)
- Webdav (http extension)
- Using a miniature (for Android) web server with file manager.
- ssh / telnet and netcat and pipes.  (Requires technical know-how)

I can think of more esoteric ways, but they are not practical or worth listing (some kind of compiled or FUSE shared block device)

Answer (score 0):

There are various server-client protocols, with servers and clients that can be run on either Android or PC. Where you install the server or client app doesn't matter, but clients are typically lighter so would prefer the Android device, thus are also probably more available in the app store.

For example the common **ES file explorer** (Android app) has:

- built-in SMB (branded "LAN") client
- FTP(s) client
- SFTP/SCP client
- FTP server (branded Remote Manager)

The quickest solution in my experience is the **Airdroid** app. Android web allows one to:

- access the phone via wifi using a web browser interface on the PC. Either LAN or remotely, remote requires making an account.
- They also have a desktop client, which I assume just reverses the web-server/web-client roles.

Alternatively, if you do not have a LAN but want to use wifi because of its practical benefits, there is [Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct). Implementations will probably use FTP or similar for the actual transfer protocol.

It seems you want to automate file transfer by pulling files from multiple Android FTP servers using a PC script. But you have data corruption. Consider changing the FTP server app (maybe use SMB) or checking the wifi signal.

Comment: Note: While ES File Explorer has been a respected tool in the past, a few years ago it became clear the product contains "features" that do a lot of phoning home to servers. Unnecessary amounts of such communication. For this reason this product is roundly considered VERY insecure and should not be used.